# What is the best practice to detect users' screen width?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

In my joomla website, I have a module that outputs 1 item by default, in its help.php file, there is something like

```
$items = 1;
$db->setQuery($query, 0, $items)
```

Now I want to detect if users' screen width is less than a certain value, if yes, then get only 1 item, else get 4 items. What is the best practice to do it?

I can just set $items to 4 and use javascript to eliminate the other 3 items, but this is not a perfect solution because excessive data will be downloaded. My questions are:
1) can PHP alone detect client's screen width?
2) If no and I have to use javascript/ajax, I am thinking add

```
<script>
    var w = screen.width;
    href = location.href;
    if (location.search){
       href = href + '&screenWidth=' + w;
    } else
    href = href + '?screenWidth=' + w;
</script>
```

to every page and use `$_GET['screenWidth]` to get the screen width value in the helper.php file, is this a good practice? Is this gonna mess up with output buffer sif there is any) set by my CMS(joomla)?

Comment: php can do NOTHING to detects screen widths. it's purely a server-side language. you need client-side involvement, which means JS.

Comment: You could use ajax to load additional content based on the screen width that you detect in javascript... But personally I hate it when I get an incomplete web-site on my phone and I would recommend a responsive design approach where you just change the presentation and not the content itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the items a class with CSS that will hide them on mobile.

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .some-class{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect the screen size with PHP cause it is only run on the server. You can try [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) it wont tell you the screen size but it will let you know what kind of device it is.